# Plugin jquery para manipular imágenes

Tags: jquery, imagen

Estaba buscando un plugin, preferiblemente en jquery (aunque no excluyente), para poder hacer algo parecido a lo siguiente:

Quiero que sobre una imagen (o sobre un lienzo blanco de un tamaño que ponga el usuario) el usuario pueda poner una serie de textos (nombre, edad, etc) y colocarlos donde el quiera moviendolos con el ratón.

Y una vez finalizado eso que pueda imprimirlo y que quede colocado en la posición que los puso.

Ejemplo:

Si tengo un diploma en el que quiero poner el nombre en la mitad y debajo la edad, que usuario coloque esos dos textos, le de a imprimir y queden bien colocados.

Comment: Hola user. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Esta pregunta se *basa en opiniones* porque pides *recomendaciones* de librerias. Has de buscar por tu cuenta. Una pregunta valida seria, usando cierta libreria, tener problemas al arrastrar un elemento. Entonces mostrarias lo intentado y los errores obtenidos. Mira [ask] para más informacion. Un saludo (por cierto, jQuery es una libreria asi que imagino que te refierse a otra libreria tambien en JS)

Comment: Quizás [Fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/) sirva para lo que necesitas. No es un plugin de jQuery, pero puede funcionar si la imagen es SVG.

Comment: Muchas gracias!, puede ser que eso sea lo que necesito. Lo probaré a ver